# Display text block if number value is lower or higher in input with select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, input

The goal is: IF I select **MORE** option then in input I must write `>=0.008`. If I select **LESS** option then in input I must write `>=0.002` and If I select something else then I must write `>=0.005` and display **cal-block** if value is not as required (else - hide).

So if I write what is required in the input, hide the **cal-price** block. It would be great if it could display automatically after write something in input without mouse click anywhere (realtime).

I prepared code below which won't work:

```
<select>
  <option value="MORE">More</option>
  <option value="LESS">Less</option>
  <option value="OTHER">Other</option>
</select>


<div class="cal-price">The price is too low</div>
<input type="text" class="check-price-js" value="0.005"/>

<script>
if($('MORE').val()is active){
  $('input.check-price-js').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val()>=0.008){
      $('div.cal-price').css('display', 'none');
    } elseif {
      $('div.cal-price').css('display', 'block');
    });
} elseif ($('LESS').val()is active){
  $('input.check-price-js').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val()>=0.002){
      $('div.cal-price').css('display', 'none');
    } elseif {
      $('div.cal-price').css('display', 'block');
    });
} else {
  $('input.check-price-js').on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val()>=0.005){
    $('div.cal-price').css('display', 'none');
  } elseif {
    $('div.cal-price').css('display', 'block');
  });
}
</script>

<style>
.cal-price {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `$('MORE').val()is active` is not valid javascript

Comment: Alright. I doesn't know how to check if value in option is selected so I added "is active". If you could write working code, I'll be very grateful and I'll accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will fire when the SELECT option changes and gets the value of the selected option

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $("select option").filter(":selected").val();
})
```

Once you have the `selected` value you can us it for whatever tests/check you want to do.
Note: I've just used 'select' in my jQuery selector, you'll want to use a class or ID instead.

Comment: What code do you still need? I also feel that at this point you should try to proceed by yourself, at least until you hit the next problem you can't overcome. That's how you get better